# Resume from Suspend fails on Samsung X360 laptop

Tags: 11.04, hardware, laptop, suspend

I just upgraded to Natty and after the upgrade on the laptop suspend is no longer working as before.

Before 11.04 I closed the lid, the laptop powered down. When I opened the lid and pressed the power button for a short time it would power up again and I could log in and continue working.

Now there are 2 problems:

a) no power down on lid closed (I am using the 'suspend' from the menu - no idea what this is called in unity -> upper right corner in the panel). **Update:** it does power down I found out it just takes a very long time to trigger (30 seconds or longer)

b) much worse: no power up after suspend. I need to turn off the laptop completely and reboot. I checked and all tools that I know of are installed: acpi-support, laptop-mode-tools, pm-tools

I have no idea how this could be fixed.

The laptop is a Samsung X360 if that helps any. I am not using any proprietary graphics drivers. (I think the graphics card is intel based)

Update: I found the following line in several logfiles in `/var/log`

```
May  8 09:34:40 MyLaptop kernel: [    1.095713] i2c-core: driver [adp5520] using legacy suspend method
```

Update 2: this is how suspend looked in /var/log/messages before natty:

```
[11905.244790] PM: late suspend of devices complete after 32.636 msecs
[12832.968226] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[12833.232083] PM: suspend of drv:HDA Intel dev:0000:00:1b.0 complete after 119.668 msecs
[12833.268081] PM: suspend of drv:sky2 dev:0000:06:00.0 complete after 159.422 msecs
[12833.268122] PM: suspend of drv:pcieport dev:0000:00:1c.3 complete after 155.763 msecs
[12833.340925] PM: suspend of drv:sd dev:0:0:0:0 complete after 355.982 msecs
[12833.340964] PM: suspend of drv:scsi dev:target0:0:0 complete after 355.898 msecs
[12833.340986] PM: suspend of drv:scsi dev:host0 complete after 355.666 msecs
[12833.420083] PM: suspend of drv:ahci dev:0000:00:1f.2 complete after 308.204 msecs
[12833.420116] PM: suspend of drv: dev:pci0000:00 complete after 307.034 msecs
[12833.420146] PM: suspend of devices complete after 451.541 msecs
[12833.420150] PM: suspend devices took 0.452 seconds
[12833.452789] PM: late suspend of devices complete after 32.627 msecs
```

Current kernel running (output from uname -A)

2.6.38-8-generic-pae #42-Ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So today I finally had the idea to simply downgrade my kernel. I went back to 2.6.35-28-generic. This fixes the resume problem. Also it is only a work-around and brings other problems with it. For me the resume is more important. Maybe this helps other people with similar problems to narrow the causes.